# ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved выскакиевает при использовании asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio, aiomysql

такая проблема, постоянно вылетала следующая ошибка:

```
INFO:aiogram:Bot: BotEx [@BotEx]
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling.
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
```

БД бота висела на OpenServer. Я подумал, что OS разрывает соединение через 1440сек. Перешел на MySql Server, ошибка осталась та же. Месяцами ранее мне советовали внести в свой код следующую строчку: `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())`

Используя ее мой бот запускается, но стоит мне отправить хоть одну команду (почти каждая команда - запрос в бд), как бот сразу падает и вылетает следующая ошибка:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-10' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=RuntimeError("Task <Task pending name='Task-11' coro=<Handler.notify() running at C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\aiogram\\dispatcher\\handler.py:117> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\asyncio\\tasks.py:766]> got Future <Task pending name='Task-12' coro=<Pool._wakeup() running at C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\aiomysql\\pool.py:203>> attached to a different loop")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\db.py", line 34, in user_info
    await cur.execute('SELECT FIO, Phone, Role, Rating, ChatID FROM Users '
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiomysql\cursors.py", line 239, in execute
    await self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiomysql\cursors.py", line 457, in _query
    await conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiomysql\connection.py", line 469, in query
    await self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiomysql\connection.py", line 672, in _read_query_result
    await result.read()
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiomysql\connection.py", line 1153, in read
    first_packet = await self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiomysql\connection.py", line 598, in _read_packet
    packet_header = await self._read_bytes(4)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiomysql\connection.py", line 646, in _read_bytes
    data = await self._reader.readexactly(num_bytes)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 723, in readexactly
    await self._wait_for_data('readexactly')
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 517, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-11' coro=<Handler.notify() running at C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py:117> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:766]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\handlers.py", line 419, in info
    user = await db.user_info('chatID', message.chat.id)
  File "C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\db.py", line 52, in user_info
    user.chatID = ChatID
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiomysql\utils.py", line 139, in __aexit__
    await self._pool.release(self._conn)
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-11' coro=<Handler.notify() running at C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py:117> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:766]> got Future <Task pending name='Task-12' coro=<Pool._wakeup() running at C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiomysql\pool.py:203>> attached to a different loop
```

Мой код для запуска бота и коннекта к бд:

```
import logging 
import asyncio 
import sys 
import aiomysql 
import db  
from aiomysql import create_pool 
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
 from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor  
import keyboards  
from messages import MESSAGES  
from settings import mysql  
from config import USER, PASSWORD, HOST, PORT, DATABASE, TOKEN, PAYMENTS_PROVIDER_TOKEN  

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  

client = Bot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
 dp = Dispatcher(client, storage=MemoryStorage(), loop=loop)  
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

   async def db_config():     
      if not mysql.conn:         
           try:             
               mysql.conn = await create_pool(                 
               host=HOST,                 
               port=PORT,                 
               user=USER,                 
               password=PASSWORD,                 
               db=DATABASE,                 
               charset='utf8',                 
               use_unicode=True,                 
               loop=loop             
               )          
           except aiomysql.Error as e:             
               print(f'Error connecting: {e}')             
               sys.exit(1)   

if __name__ == '__main__':     
      loop.run_until_complete(db_config())      

      from handlers import dp     
      executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```